# JavaScript get array of pairs of consecutive values

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

how can I convert an array like:

`[2, 5, 4, 0]`

into an array of pairs but not getting every pair. For example from the above array given, I'd like the following array:

`[[2, 5],[5, 4], [4, 0], [0, 2]`.

Furthermore, is it possible to have another function that gives back an array like: `[[2,5,4],[5,4,0],[4,0,2],[0,2,5]]`?

And also another one that gives back: `[[2,5,4,0],[5,4,0,2],[4,0,2,5],[0,2,5,4]]`?

Edit: I have tried the following which gives back every possible pair in the array, but it's not what I'm looking for:

```
let result = pieces[0].reduce( (acc, v, i) =>
    acc.concat(pieces[0].slice(i+1).map( w => [v, w] )),
[]);
```

This will show: `[ [ 2, 5 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 2, 0 ], [ 5, 4 ], [ 5, 0 ], [ 4, 0 ] ]`

Edit2: my problem here is that everything I have tried gives me every permutation of the two dimensional, three dimensional and four dimensional arrays, but I only want the examples above. Let's say, the permutation of consecutive values.

Comment: Hello, what did you try? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: It's totally possible and not really hard. It's more of a logic problem, requiring some thinking. You should explain what you tried and show some code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox, that question would solve the last part getting the permutations of the array, but not the first two. But thank you so much!

Comment: @Raúl [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64904542/989920) literally solves your issue

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, it doesn't because I don't want avery possible permutation in the two dimensional and three dimensional arrays, only the consecutive values. For example, that solution would give me: `[ [ 2, 5 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 2, 0 ], [ 5, 4 ], [ 5, 0 ], [ 4, 0 ] ]` and I want just `[[2, 5],[5, 4], [4, 0], [0, 2]`

Comment: Ah. thank you @Raúl for the correction

Comment: @evolutionxbox no problem, thank you for giving me possible solutions. My problem here is I only want some permutations and everything I have tried gives me every permutation, not just the ones I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```js
let arr = [2, 5, 4, 0]
function getPermutation(chunk){
    let result = arr.reduce((acc,e,i) => {
        if(i + chunk <= arr.length)
            acc.push(arr.slice(i,i+chunk))
        else
            acc.push(arr.slice(i,i+chunk).concat(arr.slice(0,(i+chunk) % arr.length)))
        return acc;
    },[])
    return result 
}

console.log(getPermutation(2))
console.log(getPermutation(3))
console.log(getPermutation(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```js
const input = [2, 5, 4, 0];

const output = [];

for(let i=0; i<input.length - 1; i++) {
    output.push([input[i], input[i+1]]);
}
output.push([input[input.length-1], input[0]]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Yes, but that would not give me the last pair `[0,2]`, I mean getting the last element and then the first one. Thank you!

Comment: @Raúl updated...

Comment: thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for the two dimensional array. Is there a way of doing another function for the two other problems I propose, the three dimensional and four dimensional?

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but @alan-omar solution was more complete to what I was looking for